# Subscribe to service function twice in angular for login

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular 7 app, I have a sign in component that calls the sign in function from the auth service. The sign in function does a http post request and then it subscribes to the response. I would like to subscribe to it in both the auth service function and component function so if the user doesn't enter the right credentials the component can tell the user + a loading spinner while it waits for the request to finish.

Sign in component:

```
 onSignIn() {
    if (this.signinForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.failedSignIn = null;
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.authService.signin(this.signinForm.value.email, this.signinForm.value.password);
    this.isLoading = false;

  }
```

Sign in function in Auth service:

```
 signin(email: string, password: string) {
    const signinData = {email: email, password: password};
       this.http.post<{userEmail: string, userId: string, token: string, refreshToken: string, expiresIn: number, userType: string }>(URL + 'signin', signinData).subscribe(response => {
        // I do stuff in here
      });
  }
```

what Id like to do essentially

```
  onSignIn() {
    if (this.signinForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.failedSignIn = null;
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.authService.signin(this.signinForm.value.email, this.signinForm.value.password).subscribe(res => {
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.isAuth = res.isAuth;
});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just return the observable from the auth service, and subscribe to it in the component. If you have a bunch of stuff that you want the service to do with it, you could write a function in the auth service that you call in the subscription from the component.

It's probably a bad idea to try to subscribe to an http call in multiple places (assuming that's possible).

auth service

```
signin(email: string, password: string) {
   const signinData = {email: email, password: password};
   return this.http.post<{userEmail: string, userId: string, token: string, refreshToken: string, expiresIn: number, userType: string }>(URL + 'signin', signinData);
} 

doStuff(){/*do stuff*/}
```

component

```
onSignIn() {
   if (this.signinForm.invalid) {
      return;
   } 
   this.failedSignIn = null;
   this.isLoading = true;
   this.authService.signin(this.signinForm.value.email, this.signinForm.value.password)
      .subscribe(res => {
          //do stuff if you want
          this.authService.doStuff();
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.isAuth = res.isAuth;
      });
}
```

Comment: Also, @TotenKopf just a suggestion, if you are manually showing a spinner, it might be a good idea to look up HTTP interceptors. You can automatically show a spinner on HTTP calls.

Comment: I do have http interceptors but theyre mainly for server errors. Im just too fog brained to figure this out. Good suggestion might look into that avenue

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/@zeljkoradic/loader-bar-on-every-http-request-in-angular-6-60d8572a21a9) is the guide I used recently. It can be improved on some (should have a counter), but it works.